# QSharedPointer from a raw pointer

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qtcore, qsharedpointer

I currently have something like this:

```
QSharedPointer<t> Qsharedfoo;
```

Now I have a raw pointer to foo as well called `rawfoo`. How can I make foo point own the raw pointer and start pointing to it. I know in boost with shared pointers we could use `boost::make_shared`
how do we do it with `QSharedPointer` ?

I want to do something like this:

```
Qsharedfoo = rawfoo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make foo point own the raw pointer and start pointing to it. I know in boost with shared pointers we could use boost::make_shared how do we do it with QSharedPointer ?

You cannot, unfortunately.

- You will always need to go through the constructor unlike make_shared.
- It is not necessarily exception safe.

In summary, you would need to go through the constructor and [operator=](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#reset-2) as follows:

```
Qsharedfoo = QSharedPointer<T>(rawfoo); // operator=() overload
```

or if you already have a reference to a pointer, then use the [reset() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#reset-2) as follows:

```
Qsharedfoo.reset(rawFoo);
```

But as mentioned in the beginning, these are not equal operations to what you are looking for.

Comment: Much like the old std::auto_ptr<T>, I too prefer to use reset() to avoid the slight overhead you mentioned.  But it appears that I may have misunderstood what MistyD really wanted to have answered.

Answer (score 6):

Straight from the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsharedpointer.html), we have something like this:

```
QSharedPointer<MyObject> obj = QSharedPointer<MyObject>(new MyObject);
```

You can basically pass your pointer in the same fashion:

```
// Here I assume that T is the class you're using for Qsharedfoo.
QSharedPointer<T> Qsharedfoo = QSharedPointer<T>(rawfoo);
```